# Byte Order Mark to read UTF-8 cvs and excel files

Tags: java, excel, utf-8

Friends

I have to use BOM ( Byte Order Mark ) to make sure that downloaded files in cvs and excel in UTF-8 formats are displayed properly.

**

> My question is can BOM be applied to FileOutputStream instead of
>   OutputStream as below ?

**

```
    String targetfileName = reportXMLFileName.substring(0, reportXMLFileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
      targetfileName += "xlsx";
     File tmpFile=new File((filePath !=null?filePath.trim():"")+"/"+templateFile);
     FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream((filePath !=null?filePath.trim():"")+"/"+targetfileName);

/* Here is the example*/
  out.write(new byte[] {(byte)0xEF, (byte)0xBB, (byte)0xBF });
  substitute(tmpFile, tmp, sheetRef.substring(1), out);
                    out.close();
```

Comment: Yes, it can - and you've already got the code. So what's the question, exactly?

Comment: @JonSkeet My Question is Im using FileoutputStream instead of OutputStream , so I want to know if BOM can be applied to FileoutputStream

Comment: You can even use a Writer (text), as in `writer.print("\uFFFE");`. For instance with: `new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), "UTF-8"))))`

Comment: Well you've got code that's trying to do it - what happened when you ran it? And why would you expect it to be a problem, given that `FileOutputStream` is a subclass of `OutputStream`?

Comment: @JoopEggen How can I use your suggestion in my case 
I have 
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream((filePath !=null?filePath.trim():"")+"/"+targetfileName);

Comment: @JonSkeet I thought of using FileOutputStream subclass instead

Comment: @AmitSharad fine, though when writing text as you do, I would expect to see `String`s being written, and a Writer subclass might be more appropiate than using `OutputStream.write(string.getBytes("UTF-8"))`.

Comment: What do you mean? `FileOutputStream` is a subclass of `OutputStream`. Why would you want to use a subclass of `FileOutputStream`?

Comment: @JoopEggen 
Please show me how to re-write      FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream((filePath !=null?filePath.trim():"")+"/"+targetfileName);
  To use PrintWriter ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(As asked in comment.)*

In the following `file` may  be File, (File)OutputStream or String (filename).

```
final String ENCODING = "UTF-8";
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(file, ENCODING))));
try {
    out.print("\ufffe"); // Write the BOM
    out.println("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"" + ENCODING + "\"?>");
    ...
} finally {
    out.close();
}
```

Or since Java 7:

```
try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(f, ENCODING))))) {
    out.print("\ufffe"); // Write the BOM
    out.println("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"" + ENCODING + "\"?>");
    ...
}
```

Working with text, makes it more natural to use a Writer, as one does not need oneself to convert string with `String.getBytes("UTF-8")`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A BOM sits at the beginning of any data stream, whether over the network or in a file. Just write the BOM to the file at the beginning in the same manner, just to a `FileOutputStream`. Anyway, remember that a FileOutputStream *is* a type of OutputStream.

Comment: what if I use Filewriter class instead of FileOutputStream like 
  String targetfileName = reportXMLFileName.substring(0, reportXMLFileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
  targetfileName += "csv";
  FileWriter fw = new FileWriter((filePath !=null?filePath.trim():"")+"/"+targetfileName);

How to use it ?

Comment: @AmitSharad Why would you use that? Use a stream you can write bytes to.